# I am getting Assertion Failed while trying simple click and move test

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Hope this helps in clarifying...
[image]

I followed ClicktoMove Test in the cpp-tests from the cocos2dx -3 version.
Whenever I click on screen I get

> Assertion Failed !
>   ......
>     File:CCLayer.cpp
>     Line:337
>     Expression:False

UPDATE!

I downloaded the latest version as mentioned on the change log "cocos2d-x-3.0 Apr.23 2014".
and this solves the problem and all the methods I mentioned here work. Thanks anyway to GameDeveloper..

Comment: What is the expression at *CCLayer.cpp Line:337* that is evaluating to false?

Comment: CCASSERT(false, "Layer#ccTouchBegan override me");

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your usage of `onTounchBegan` and `onTouchEnded` as these were Cocos2d v2 functions for implementing touch events.

What about something like this:

```
auto e=EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
e->setSwallowTouches(true);

e->onTouchBegan = [&](cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
{
    return true;
};

e->onTouchEnded = [=](cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
{
    GameLayer::touchEvent(touch);
};

cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(e,this);

void GameLayer::touchEvent(Touch* touch)
{
  std::cout << "touch event" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: ClickandMove Test uses the same ones that I used check it out here  https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/tests/cpp-tests/Classes/ClickAndMoveTest/ClickAndMoveTest.cpp

Comment: I tried that sample and it works for me. I can't really make out your code above that well. Looks like a header mixd with normal source stuff. Perhaps break it out better and I can run it and see what is going on.

Comment: I posted the snapshot for clarity .Perhaps you could show me your code.Did you just copy paste it or modified the example.??

Comment: I also tried your method but now when I close it says
"HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after normal block(#1560)at 0x0+62d718"CRT detected that application wrote memory after end of heap and buffer"..But my question specifically is why simply it doesnot work as all the tests worked  flawlessly in version 2.3